# Election: Strategic Mod Voting

Tags: discussion, election

Do you strategically mod vote?

Although I do not strategically mod vote and I have only voted positively for three moderates, I have noticed there are a lot of negative votes.

There is only one or possibly two moderators which I am against but I fhave decided not to down-vote. However, in general I have noticed many moderates are openly down-voted.

Do you think it is strategic to down-vote moderates who are not in your top selection?

**Edit Clarification:**

Strategic mod vote: up-vote the candidate you are in favor of but down vote all others regardless of election platform.

**Further Edit:**

When I say **platform** I am referring to a **election platform** such as campaign promises.

Is it necessary for downvoting for the election process?

By **choosing not** to down vote candidates of other platforms I am hurting my initial election votes? If people only vote positively for candidate (which appears to be the majority of voters) but others strategically down vote are they voting twice?

Should down voting be allowed?

Assume Tom, Dick and Harry run for the election.

Tom (Assume Tom has 2 people that vote for him but also down-votes Dick and Harry)

Dick (Assume Dick has 2 people that votes for him but do not down-vote)

Harry (Assume Harry has 2 people that vote for him but also down-votes Dick and Tom)

Each candidate should have one vote each but say Harry runs on  a particular platform that appeals to a certain type of person.

**The results are:**

Tom 1

Dick -1

Harry 1

However, they should have equal amounts of positive votes. The down votes actually detract from the personality that refrain from down-voting.

Just for discussion...

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "strategic"?

Comment: Are you choosing mods based on _platform_? Seriously? I'd prefer Grace Hopper to Rambo!

Comment: @belisarius - I think the OP means their *election* platform not their *development* platform. At least I hope so.

Comment: @ChrisF It seems so, after re-reading carefully :)

Comment: I think I've been voting wrong. Could everyone who is pro-.NET please identify themselves so I may appropriately downvote?

Answer (score 20):

**Heck yeah!** Why *else* would you down-vote? Odd numbers annoy you? You just like clicking things? Ok, those are good reasons too... But strategy is better. And my strategy is, "down-vote everyone I don't want to be a moderator".

Don't forget: these are the *primaries* - the point is to whittle down the number of candidates, not pick a final set of moderators. You'll have a chance later to vote *only* for the candidates you think will make the *best* moderators.

Comment: +1: Exactly my point. If I am given the ability to downvote which would posivitively affect my candidate, why wouldnt I? Yet the majority of voters (judging by the ratio) appear to only to vote for their favourites.

Comment: @snmcdonald: people opting not to use their votes is a time-honored tradition when it comes to elections. To thine own self be true...

Comment: @Shog9: Very good point, but don't you think you are taking advantage of their generosity of only voting in good spirit? I mean if they had also down-voted their opponents as well wouldn't it be possibly a different outcome?

Comment: @snmcdonald: No. If I like kodos and you like kang, and I vote and you don't, then I'm not *taking advantage* of you. If I vote and you vote, and I down-vote and you don't... I'm *still* not taking advantage of you. *Now...* If I post an eloquent rant arguing against down-voting and *then* go down-vote, while you, swayed my by words, refrain... *That* would be taking advantage.

Comment: @Shog9: Good point. Judging by your opinion (and the current system), downvoting is part of the election process and should be taken advantage of.

Comment: Odd numbers bug me a lot actually.

Answer (score 18):

I don't (didn't). I voted up the ones I wanted to see as Moderators. I voted down the ones that I didn't want to see as Moderators. For those I was ambivalent about I didn't vote at all.

But that's just me.

Comment: +1: I have only voted for my favourite candidate based upon platforms. I have not (as of yet) downvoted opponents based upon ethics. (However, I could be swayed).

Comment: This is also what I did.

Answer (score 6):

I downvote those that I do not believe will make good moderators. I expect every other nominee to do the same.  I believe there are many good choices in the primary list, and I also know from experience that some of those potential moderators are not good choices for the community.

I would be doing the community a disservice if I did not vote my conscience.

It does seem like there is a conflict of interest, doesn't it?  At face value at least -- but the important thing is that no matter the outcome of the election, we choose moderators who have the values of the community in their heart.

Comment: It was probably intended that downvotes be used as such. I suppose all things can be abused.

Comment: @snmcdonald Yes it can; but we can take solace in the fact that there are only 30 moderator nominees.  If there were 4,000, we might have a problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't downvote anyone. I did upvote those whose names I recognised, after first confirming that the reason I recognised them wasn't because we'd had some massive difference of opinion in the past (on moderator-type functions of course, not tech answers - in other words, close votes, edits and so forth).

I figured the bods I hadn't heard of may well be very good moderators. So those I recognised as good moderators got +1, those who I'd never seen before got nothing.

There's perhaps one or two people I *would* have downvoted had they put themselves forward :-) But they didn't.

Answer (score -4):

I don't downvote at all. I only have one downvite on Meta and that was becuase I didn't like the question.

I think users should have a limit of 5 upvotes and 2 or 3 downvotes per election.

But then again I don't make the choice,

Comment: In the *next* stage of the election process, you'll have no down-votes and limited up-votes.